# Setting page url dynamically in Geb

Tags: groovy, automation, geb

In this scenario, I want to navigate from the main page to the sub page and perform some actions. The url of the sub page is dynamically generated, but the page content is the same. This is what I have tried so far:

In the main class:

```
to MainPage
    SubPageButton.click()
    to SubPage
    SelectAddressButton.click()
```

In the Page class:

```
public class SubPage extends Page {
    static url = getCurrentUrl()
    static content = {
        SelectAddressButton { $("button", 0) }
    }
}
```

I have alternatively tried (without any success)

1. Defining the static content for the sub page ( SelectAddressButton )
   in the Page object for the main page.
2. Defining the sub page without the url

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you are failing with Page w/o url, because you try to navigate it with `to`. When you do a `click` you can provide expected Page. See example below.

Comment: Thanks. That's where I was going wrong. Instead of using 'to', doing the at check as you had mentioned in your answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work, as static fields are initialized when the class is loaded.

However, you can use `go "http://my_dynamic_url_string"` in your specification and then make your assertions. The `at` assertion would work here too.

Also, if your "dynamic" url can be parametrized you should have a look at [Advanced Page Navigation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/pages.html).

Defining a `Page` without a `url` static field should work. I've used it a lot. Currently I have it working with Geb '0.10.0' and use it via `withNewWindow { link.click(CustomPage) }` and it does static `at` verification for me. Or you can put logic in methods, and call them in closure you pass to `withNewWindow`.

For example (untested):

```
class CustomPage {
  static content = {
      SelectAddressButton { $("button", 0) }
  }

  static at = { "check smth" }

  def orSomehowLikeThis() {
    assert "smth"
    SelectAddressButton.click() // accessing content
  }
}

withNewWindow { link.click(CustomPage) } {
  orSomehowLikeThis()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can I define the static content for the sub page? I have tried defining in the main page but it does not work. Defining the page without the url does not work either though that method is used in examples.

Comment: @dshgna Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Override the method `getPageUrl` in your `Page` class.

Go through source code Spec, Page. Notice how getPageUrl is being called.